# How to set a color filter for XWalkView?

Tags: java, android, canvas, filter, paint

I am currently working on my web browser [Cornowser](https://github.com/xdevs23/Cornowser), which uses the Crosswalk engine, and I ran into a problem.
I want to implement color modes, as they are in UltimateBrowserProject.

But the color filters don't apply.
I tried setting the layer type and passing the `Paint` with the color filter.

Here is the source code:

```
// Handle color modes

public void drawWithColorMode() {
    Logging.logd("Applying web render color mode...");
    RenderColorMode.ColorMode cm = CornBrowser.getBrowserStorage().getColorMode();
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    final float[] negativeColor = {
            -1.0f, 0, 0, 0, 255,    // Red
            0, -1.0f, 0, 0, 255,    // Green
            0, 0, -1.0f, 0, 255,    // Blue
            0, 0, 0,  1.0f, 0       // Alpha
    };
    final float[] darkColor = {
            1f, 0, 0, 0, -255,
            0, 1f, 0, 0, -255,
            0, 0, 1f, 0, -255,
            0, 0, 0, 1f,    0
    };
    final float[] invertColor = {
            -1f, 0, 0, 0, 0,
            0, -1f, 0, 0, 0,
            0, 0, -1f, 0, 0,
            0, 0, 0, 1f,  0
    };

    Logging.logd("Found color mode: " + cm.mode);

    switch(cm.mode) {
        case RenderColorMode.ColorMode.NORMAL:
            Logging.logd("Applying normal color mode");
            paint.setColorFilter(null);
            break;
        case RenderColorMode.ColorMode.DARK:
            Logging.logd("Applying dark mode");
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(darkColor));
            break;
        case RenderColorMode.ColorMode.NEGATIVE:
            Logging.logd("Applying negative mode");
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(negativeColor));
            break;
        case RenderColorMode.ColorMode.INVERT:
            Logging.logd("Applying inverted mode");
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(invertColor));
            break;
        case RenderColorMode.ColorMode.GREYSCALE:
            Logging.logd("Applying greyscale");
            ColorMatrix m = new ColorMatrix();
            m.setSaturation(0);
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(m));
            break;
        default:
            Logging.logd("Warning: Unknown color mode " + cm.mode + ".");
            break;
    }

    Logging.logd("Setting layer type...");
    setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, paint);
}
```

I also tried it by overriding `draw(canvas)` but it's the same result.

Does anyone know how to set a color filter for XWalkView?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

It seems to be that `SurfaceView` doesn't support color filters.
How to do it anyways?

**UPDATE 2:**
Seems that this question is not getting so much attention... I edited my source code, how it should work, but it doesn't work, please check it, logcat gives me following output:

```
D/Cornowser: Applying web render color mode...
D/Cornowser: Found color mode: 2
D/Cornowser: Applying negative mode
D/Cornowser: Setting layer type...
```

**Final update:**
I actually got it working by using JavaScript.
If you want to know how I solved it, look [right here](https://github.com/xdevs23/Cornowser/commit/cd4082424fd9408b4de42abe074ceeaefe5b3156).

Answer (score 0):

Override the draw(Canvas) method

write the above source code

At the end of the draw() method call invalidate()

Comment: I don't understand why you want to call invalidate in the end of draw().